# Number of possible combinations with a descending-value constraint

Tags: combinations

I'm trying to solve an engineering problem regarding the optimization of electrical steel widths to compose a transformer core. At the end, I want to know how many combination can be made with based on two parameters: The number of steps in the core ($N$) and the number of available widths ($W$).

The constraint are:

- $W>N$
- widths need to be descending order.

As an example, the following table contains the solution for $W=4$:

| N | W | Combinations | Number of combinations $C$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 4 / 3 / 2 / 1 | 4 |
| 2 | 4 | 4-3 / 4-2 / 4-1 / 3-2 / 3-1 / 2-1 | 6 |
| 3 | 4 | 4-3-2 / 4-3-1 / 4-2-1 / 3-2-1 | 4 |
| 4 | 4 | 4-3-2-1 | 1 |

What I want is to find a function (with $W$ and $N$ as input) that gives me the $NC$. I couldn't find it so far.

Comment: [Binomial coefficient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient)

Comment: Two words solved the problem. Thank you. I really love math, despite not having been well educated in it

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment done by @Daniel Mathis, it's clear that the problem is equivalent to the Binomial Coefficient. So, it could be solved by the following formula:
$$C=\frac{W!}{N!(W-N)!}$$
using the $N$ and $W$ as presented in the question.